# User credentials are sent in clear text in asp.net website

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I run an Audit on my website and it shows that  "User credentials are sent in clear text"

Form authentication is enabled in my website and it should be accessed from anywhere.

How to send password in encrypted format?

is SSL the only option, I read around and found that enabling Digest authentication can do this also, is there any disadvantage if I change Basic to digest in IIS?

Comment: You could do some client-side processing (javascript perhaps?) that encodes it before sending it, but you're better off with SSL.

Comment: You'll need a certificate so you can run on https.

Comment: @BradChristie do you have any code for client-side processing ?

Comment: It's best you employ SSL. As the term implies "client side" is **client side** (therefore it can be inspected, taken apart, etc. by anyone with the time and persistence). Unsure what you mean by "BASIC"? You mean "basic authentication"? If so, you **must** use SSL. The next question is, where is "Forms authentication" if you use Basic (via IIS)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

Answer (score 3):

> and found that enabling Digest authentication can do this also, is there any disadvantage if I change Basic to digest in IIS?

The main disadvantage is that it doesn't work with Forms authentication. 
The Digest setting eliminates sending plain-text username/password for Windows authentication only. 
The only IIS setting that applies to Forms is "Allow Anonymous Access".

This is a well-researched and discussed topic. You need SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You might be hashing it with md5 on the client, but you're not passing that to the server, you're obviously still passing whatever is in the password box.  Hashing the password on the client before you send it is a bad idea for many reasons.